# Good .net4 profiler

Tags: .net-4.0, profiling, profiler

What is a good profiler for .NET 4.0? I'm willing to spend some money, but not too much (say up to £50)

I'm developing games for windows phone and xbox using XNA, which means that the projects are commercial. I mention it because I've seen several which are free for non commercial use.

Extra points for Visual studio integration.

Nb. I'm using Visual Studio Professional 2010

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: This question was (and still is) specific to .net4, which at the time had very few free/affordable profilers

Comment: Understood, just linking for cross-reference reasons (ppl searching and for your benefit too in case you didn't see it).

Comment: Ah fair enough, I thought it was an effort to close the question. Thanks for the link :)

Answer (score 5):

A tremendously under-advertised free profiler is the [SharpDevelop Profiler](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/siegfried_pammer/archive/2009/04/04/introducing-a-new-tool-in-sharpdevelop-the-profiler.aspx).

Screenshot:

[image: SharpDevelop]
<sub>(source: [sharpdevelop.net](http://community.sharpdevelop.net/blogs/siegfried_pammer/profiler/post1/view.png))</sub>

It is really powerful, and supports the tremendously undocumented PSQL (Profiler SQL as they call it). For example, I can filter all the functions I am interested in by entering this in to the query bar:

```
for f in Functions where f.Name.Contains("Foo") select f
```

Answer (score 3):

The [EQATEC Profiler](http://www.eqatec.com/profiler) profiles just about everything .NET, including what you need:

- **Full .NET** 2.0 and above
- **Windows Phone 7**, both Silverlight and XNA apps
- **Silverlight** 2.0 and above
- **NET CF** 2.0 and above (WinCE, Windows Mobile)
- **Xbox** XNA (lacking integrated deployment to Xbox-device, though)

Long story short: the only thing it *doesn't* profile is .NET 1.x (full/netcf). No other profilers in the World works on this many .NET platforms. It's also known for being quite easy to use.

Comment: +1, and the basic version is free. Too bad it doesn't do line-level profiling.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2010 has a pretty good builtin profiler (only available in the Premium and Ultimate editions though)

Another great profiler is [dotTrace](http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/).

I only listed the profilers I *know* support .Net 4.0 right now, but do take a look at [this older question about .Net profilers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers). Maybe some of them have recently added support for .Net 4.0 too. In any case, I don't think there are any *new* profilers out there, since it's a pretty complex topic.

Comment: @Maruricio: does dotTrace have .NET 4.0 support yet?

Comment: Unfortunately I can get a free copy of visual studio pro, so I'm stuck using pro

Comment: @John: yes, dotTrace 4.0 beta (latest version as of this writing) supports .Net 4.0

Comment: Unfortunately at £156 dotTrace is way beyond my price range

Comment: @Martin: edited my answer, take a look at the other question

Comment: For VS2010, the profiler is in Premium and Ultimate (there are no "Team" editions in VS2010).

Comment: Does the VS 2010 profiler support profiling at the source line level?

Answer (score 2):

[Slim Tune](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=563041) is a great profiler

Comment: SlimTune doesn't currently support .net4

Comment: SlimTune now supports .net 4.0, has for a while.  Pretty decent profiler.

Answer (score 0):

Everybody wants a profiler, but [this low-tech method](http://www.wikihow.com/Optimize-Your-Program%27s-Performance) works just fine.

Comment: While it *is possible* to do this, it's not really viable, you waste too much time.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: It is understandable to have such opinions if it has not been tried. In my experience (and others on SO) it finds problems very quickly, while people are still trying to get their profilers installed, get them running, figure out what the output means, and realize they don't always tell what they need to know.

Comment: ... Here's a list of myths that many profilers are prone to, including the one in VS, if I'm not mistaken: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777556/alternatives-to-gprof/1779343#1779343

Comment: I don't know why you would assume that kind of things about me. I do use low-tech/poor-man profiling methods (in fact I have blogged about one: http://bugsquash.blogspot.com/2009/08/poor-man-profiler-with-windsor.html) but I still think a good profiler is better and faster in 99% of the cases, at least for the kind of code *I've* been handling so far in my short career.

Comment: @Mauricio Scheffer: Sorry - I know people on SO are just trying to help each other. In my long career I see people trying out motorcycles, Volkswagens, Maseratis, when a rowboat does the job (though it's OK to put a motor on it). It's a different perspective - not a top-down approach of measuring time, and being concerned about accuracy, but rather a bottom-up approach of asking what it is doing and *why*, on only a rough percentage basis, looking at lines, not functions, and looking at wall-clock time, not CPU time, ignoring irrelevant stuff like recursion.